# Cassandra 2.0 Helenus Driver in node.js TTL and TS returned are incorrect

Tags: cassandra, thrift, helenus

Cassandra version used is 2.0. With Cassandra Helenus Driver, TTL and TS returned don't seem to be correct. Not sure what I am missing here.

Here is the npm installation information:

```
cassandra-client@0.14.7 node_modules/cassandra-client
├── node-uuid@1.4.1
├── async@0.2.9
├── thrift@0.9.0
└── whiskey@0.8.4 (gex@0.0.1, sprintf@0.1.2, rimraf@1.0.1, simplesets@1.1.6, terminal@0.1.3, logmagic@0.1.4, underscore@1.5.2, magic-templates@0.1.1, istanbul@0.1.44)
```

Here is the example

```
cqlsh:mykeyspace> INSERT INTO users (user_id,  fname, lname)    VALUES (1749, 'john', 'smith5') using TTL 3000;
cqlsh:mykeyspace> SELECT writetime(fname) FROM users;



writetime(fname)
------------------
 1379455363318000
 1379280881300000
 1379280882172000
 1379460416737000

(4 rows)

cqlsh:mykeyspace> SELECT ttl(fname) FROM users;

 ttl(fname)
------------
       null
       null
       null
       2992

(4 rows)
```

Node.js Snippet

```
var helenus = require ('helenus');

var conn = new helenus.ConnectionPool({
       host      : 'localhost:9160',
       keyspace   : 'mykeyspace',
       user       : '',
       password   : '',
       timeout    : 3000,
       cqlVersion : '3.0.0'

        //cqlVersion : '3.0.0' // specify this if you're using Cassandra 1.1 and want to use CQL 3
  });

  conn.on('error', function(err){
    console.error(err.name, err.message);
  });

 conn.connect(function(err, keyspace){
    if(err){
      throw(err);
    } else {
        conn.cql("SELECT fname FROM users", function(err, results){
        console.log(err, results);
        console.log('Here we are!');

        results.forEach(function(row){
        //all row of result
           row.forEach(function(name,value,ts,ttl){
           //all column of row
           console.log(name,value,ts,ttl);
          });

         });
      });
    }
 });
```

Here is the output

```
Here we are!
fname john Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) null
fname john Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) null
fname john Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) null
fname john Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) null
```

Comment: So what's wrong ? What did you expect as output to the CQL query ?

Comment: CQL Query through node app should be printing the correct time of creation (somewhere around Sept 17 for all of them and TTL for the last line should have been approximately 2900. If you see, the last item was created with TTL of 3000 using 'cqlsh', and the node app was executed within a few seconds. 'cqlsh' reports the times correctly, while Helenus node execution does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much everything I'm reading on the [Helenus project page](https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client) makes me think that it's not compatible with Apache Cassandra 2.0/CQL3

To exemplify:

> Since 0.14.1, the client supports Apache Cassandra 1.2.x
>   in CQL 2 compatibility mode.
>
> By default Cassandra 1.2.x uses CQL 3 so you need to turn
>   the CQL 2 compatibility mode on by passing 'cql_version':
>   '2.0.0' attribute to Connection / PooledConnection
>   constructor in the options object.

and

> If you use cqlsh which ships with Cassandra 1.2.x or a
>   newer version of cqlsh which defaults to CQL 3 you need to
>   pass -2 argument to it, otherwise the client won't be able
>   to read column family definitions (#67).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this and report.

Comment: I switched back to C* 1.2. Everything works Okay. Helenus is not compatible as yet for C* 2.0.